# Stargazer and r: how to line up rows for coefficients of the same name with multiple polynomial regressions

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, polynomials, stargazer

I would like to organize my table to be more condensed. I have 4 polynomial regressions that all have the same variables but use different degrees. Please note I am producing an output with HTML not latex. The code bellow best describes my problem:

This is my code:

```
library(stargazer)
attach(mtcars)

preg1 = lm(mpg~poly(disp, 1))
preg2 = lm(mpg~poly(disp, 2))
preg3 = lm(mpg~poly(disp, 3))
preg4 = lm(mpg~poly(disp, 4))

stargazer(preg1, preg2, preg3, preg4, type="html", align=TRUE,
          covariate.labels=c("X1", 
                             "X1", "X2", 
                             "X1", "X2", "X3", 
                             "X1", "X2", "X3","X4"))
```

however, it produces this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czUMX.jpg

I edited the HTML code to give an example of the output I would like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwAjR.jpg

however, it is inefficient to edit through the messy stargazer HTML every time I need to do this

Comment: hi, it is hard to help you without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), could you add one? I would say the problem comes from ```covariate.labels```. What is the outcome when you remove that part?

Comment: @bretauv I will update with a reproducible example from the mtcars data set, thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is an "alternative" rather than a solution. I create a new column in `mtcars` for each degree of the polynomial form, and then I apply regression on these new columns:

```
library(stargazer)
library(dplyr)
attach(mtcars)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
  mutate("disp2" = disp^2, "disp3" = disp^3, "disp4" = disp^4)

attach(mtcars2)

test1 = lm(mpg~disp)
test2 = lm(mpg~disp + disp2)
test3 = lm(mpg~disp + disp2 + disp3)
test4 = lm(mpg~disp + disp2 + disp3 + disp4)

stargazer(test1, test2, test3, test4, type="html", align=TRUE)
```

I recognize that this is far from being ideal since it requires to create new variables, which can be very long if you want to go the tenth degree for example. I'm still looking for a solution but meanwhile, maybe you can use that alternative.

**Note:** [apparently](https://datascienceplus.com/fitting-polynomial-regression-r/), `poly` solves the correlation problem between variables at different degrees:
*However, note that `q`, `I(q^2)` and `I(q^3)` will be correlated and correlated variables can cause problems. The use of poly() lets you avoid this by producing orthogonal polynomials, therefore I’m going to use the first option.*

That makes my alternative again less useful.

Answer (score 0):

One way that worked for me was renaming the covariates when fitting the model and then changing the covariate labels when calling the stargazer function.

Example:

```
    names(reg1$coefficients) <- c('Constant','x')
    summary(reg1)
    names(reg2$coefficients) <- c('Constant','x', 'x2')
    summary(reg2)
    
    stargazer( reg1, reg2, type = "html",align=TRUE, 
    covariate.labels=c("Intercept", "x", "x<sup>2</sup>"), digits = 2)`
```